# Bool is not a subtype of ObjCBool - swift 2 beta 5

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7-beta5

Just upgraded to the latest beta and i'm getting this error:  [image]

Any ideas?

Code is:

```
func testFileStatusNotifications() {

    let x : XCNotificationExpectationHandler = { (n : NSNotification!) -> Bool in

        // Extract userInfo
        let u = n.userInfo!

        let dict = u.values.first as! [String : Double]
        let percent = dict["percent"]!

        return (percent > 10)
    }
```

It appears that the handler type must have changed:

```
typealias XCNotificationExpectationHandler = (NSNotification) -> ObjCBool
```

as it now is of type `ObjCBool`

Answer (score 0):

```
func testFileStatusNotifications() {

    let x : XCNotificationExpectationHandler = { (n : NSNotification!) -> ObjCBool in

        // Extract userInfo
        let u = n.userInfo!
        let dict = u.values.first as! [String : Double]
        let percent = dict["percent"]!

        let ret =  (percent > 10)
        return ObjCBool(ret)
    }
```

That seems to have fixed things.